# IEEEeqnarray - Centred numbering

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, labels, equation-number

I love IEEEeqnarray, but after searching through Stack I haven't found a good solution for grouping equations under a single number which is vertically centred with the rest of the equations.

Something similar to:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:equation_name}
\begin{aligned}
y_1 &= m_1 x + b_2\\
y_2 &= m_2 x + b_2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IEEEeqnarraybox` with vertical centering. Note that the first optional argument is text to typeset in front of the box, so you need the second one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
y_1 &= m_1 x + b_2\\
y_2 &= m_2 x + b_2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[][c]{rCl}
y_1 &= m_1 x + b_2\\
y_2 &= m_2 x + b_2
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please accept my slightly belated, but nevertheless heartfelt, congratulations on passing the 1million rep point mark on TeX.SE!!!